# How to clean the geometry good way?

Tags: modeling

I tried to union all the mesh.But inside all the geometry getting mess. I tried to boolean again, but still find some mesh not join and i want to delete and make it clean. Any good way to make it clean.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I open your file, your geometry looks total clean.  Did you Apply the boolean or leave something out?  There are only two objects (Cube.003, Cube.004)   See my screencap at https://www.dropbox.com/s/mw9cikizzpoc3av/geometry.PNG?dl=0

Comment: @james_t yes its kept for boolean, for me it did not work so i keep it hidden. Plz hide it or delete or u can use for boolean if it works for you let me know.

Comment: it looks like your mesh is non manifold,with several meshes and overlapping vertices, I guess it doesn't help

Comment: @moonboots any option to merge or union the geometry inside

Comment: You should try to union all the meshes into one, remove overlapping vertices, then try again

Comment: I tried union the mesh but its not getting union as expected.

Comment: because your meshes need to be non-manifold before you union